# Google Sheets COLUMN TOP ArrayFormula to calculate ROW wise which require ROW-wise ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Ref link below.

Essentially the aim to get a geometric progression with each term repeated X times.

The correct result on the sheet is obtained using an ArrayFormula across a row. This requires copying the formula column wise.

What I would like is a single ArrayFormula atop the column, that calcluates the results row wise (as indicated). My attempt on the sheet fails.

[sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vCMtnS_FGUEJ-HOofcy-ebK4NOhbDYM3CyTUcTX0cls/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It seems that due to the usage of the `SEQUENCE` function in your current implementation, you need to use `ARRAYFORMULA` to proceed on repeating the next succeeding numbers on a single row. It looks like it is impossible to use `ARRAYFORMULA` within an `ARRAYFORMULA` for the next rows. With that being said, would you want to consider using a custom Google Sheet function instead through Apps Script [like this](https://imgur.com/a/c8fKHxi)?

Comment: Prefer not to use a custom function. Built in functions are really fast. And the odd - customs functions "Error loading data" happens now and then.

Also, do not have to use SEQUENCE. Any other method that delivers the result is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New tab on your sample sheet called MK.Help.  This formula is in cell E1.

It uses what I (and some others probably) call a query header smush.  it takes advantage of query()'s built in ability to concatenate multiple header rows.  It feeds a Transposed array into a query, then pretends like the whole thing is all header rows by setting the 3rd parameter of QUERY() equal to a very large number.  It's common with this trick to use 9^9 or 9^99 which is just a very concise way of writing a very large number (9 to the 99th power).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    ROW(A:A) = 1,
      "Result",
      TRANSPOSE(
        SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(
          QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
            REPT(
              IF(
                SEQUENCE(1,MAX(C:C),0) > C:C,,
                  ROUND(A:A * B:B ^ SEQUENCE(1,MAX(C:C),0)) & CHAR(10)
              ),
              D:D
            )
          ),, 9^9)
        ), CHAR(10), ",")
      )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thats quite incredible. Will learn from this.

Comment: There is still an issue with this formula - If you look at your sheet, the first row has 3 items repeated 3 times. It should be  2 items repeated 3 times. I'm trying to figure out how MAX() works (in your formula) with regards to ArrayFormula.

Comment: I was lazy to check your solution because it is all in one line. :) Should've done it before writing the same one.

Comment: @kishkin Ha! yeah, for some reason, i'm the only person that seems to find the multi-line format *harder* to read!  I think it's because I don't come from a real coding background at all.

Comment: @RiyazMansoor Is there still an issue with my formula? I just looked at the first row on the MK.Idea sample tab and I see 2 items repeated 3 times.

Comment: @MattKing line "SEQUENCE(1,MAX(C:C),0) > C:C" I changed the ">" to ">="

Comment: @RiyazMansoor Ah understood.  and that made it work as you hoped?

Comment: @MattKing Yup. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Same solution as Matt's, the only difference is that repetition is done using regex.*

Try this (on sheet `kishkin`):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    A2:A = "",,
      REGEXREPLACE(
        REGEXREPLACE(
          TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
            IF(
              SEQUENCE(1, MAX(C2:C)) > C2:C,,
                ROUND(A2:A * B2:B ^ SEQUENCE(1, MAX(C2:C),)) & ","
            )
          ),, MAX(C2:C))),
          "[^,\s]+,?",
          REPT("$0", D2:D)
        ),
        "\s+|,\s*$",
      )
  )
)
```

[image]